# How to reset salesforce community password when SSO is enabled

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I created a salesforce community using Partner community licence. I enabled some contacts as community user. so a corresponding user is created for them. Now i want to reset the password for them. My org is single sign on enabled . So i am not able to reset or set any password for those users. Any help regarding how to set the password for those users will be great. Currently when i am clicking on reset password button, it is showing me the error -

Password not reset for Single Sign-On User

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer. We have a checkbox on community profile to disable single sign on. haha.. :)

Comment: So is this custom functionality or standard?

Comment: Its a standard functionality.